# Plot histograms as lines

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I want to plot several histograms of time data (1 week long) on the same plot as lines.

I have time data:

```
> dput(head(ts))
structure(c(1364421605.227, 1364375025.034, 1364376298.393, 1364375002.928, 
1364393158.084, 1364423268.856), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
```

and I want to plot its histogram. [`hist(ts,breaks=7*24)`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/hist.html) works fine, but it uses the `h` plot type which will obscure other histogram plots I want to add (I know I can use transparent colors - [`rainbow`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/palettes.html) with `alpha=0.5`, but I really want to see the lines).

I tried

```
> hist(ts, breaks = 7*24, type="l")
Warning messages:
1: In title(main = main, sub = sub, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, ...) :
  graphical parameter "type" is obsolete
Calls: hist -> hist.POSIXt -> myplot -> plot -> plot.histogram -> title
2: In axis(2, ...) : graphical parameter "type" is obsolete
Calls: hist -> hist.POSIXt -> myplot -> axis
3: In axis(side, at = z, labels = labels, ...) :
  graphical parameter "type" is obsolete
Calls: hist -> hist.POSIXt -> myplot -> axis.POSIXct -> axis
```

why is `hist` passing `type` to `title`?

I can create the histogram object and plot it separately:

```
> h <- hist(ts, breaks=7*24, plot=FALSE)
> plot(x=h$mids, y=h$density, type="l")
```

but then the `x` axis is labeled with numbers (e.d., "1364421605") not dates (e.g., "Mar 25").

I guess I am supposed to use [`axis`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/axis.html), but I would rather not handle that myself - after all, `hist` constructs just the axis I want!

Thanks!

Comment: Well, it seems that `hist` literally isn't built to do that. If you look at the code for the plot methods it literally has the rectangles hard coded with a call to `rect`. In the POSIX methods, it has some elaborate code for constructing the axes you like. So you'll probably have to replicate that axis construction (or there may be a plotting function in a package that does this already, who knows).

Comment: Also, you can see the pass of unused arguments to `title` in the help page for `hist`, specifically in the `...` section.

Comment: If you use `ggplot` instead it can put the different histograms next to each other (using different colors if you like), thus rendering the whole issue moot. See e.g. http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3/geom_histogram.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following looks weird because you only gave us six data points in your `dput`. You can plot a line plot without the x-axis and add it afterwards like so:

```
h <- hist(ts, breaks=7*24, plot=FALSE)
plot(x=h$mids, y=h$density, type="l", xaxt="n")
axis(1,at=ts,labels=format(ts,"%b-%d"))
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! except that `axis` should be called `axis(1,at=h$breaks,labels=format(as.POSIXct(h$breaks,origin="1970-01-01"),"%b %d"))`

Comment: You could also make it look less "weird" by choosing fewer bins.